# Buzzing sound when using earpods/No Buzzing sound when using headphone on pc

Tags: windows-10

Buzzing sound when using earpods/No Buzzing sound when using headphone on pc,whenever i connect and listen to music using my earpod  i hear buzzing sound, however there is no buzzing sound when i connect a headphone to the same pc, the earpod works fine on my phone,what is causing it?

Comment: Sounds like electrical/EMF interference from something... does the same occur on another device with the earpods?

Comment: It works fine on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.5mm socket on your PC is not quite long enough/too long or has poor contact with your 3.5mm earpods jack. You might find if you pull the jack out ever so slightly, the noise goes away. It's essentially a shorted connection across the poles on the jack. You might also find your earpods have an extra terminal, defined by an extra black band around the circumferance, compared to your other headphones.

This image might help explain the extra poles on the jack (ignore the banner text).

[image]